# Calculate BIg-O for 3 random permutation algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to calculate the Big-O time complexity for these 3 algorithms, but seems like I have a lack of knowledge on this topic.

1st:

```
private void firstAlgorithm(int size) {
int[] array = new int[size];
int i=0; int flag=0;
while(i<size) {
    int num=(int)(Math.random()*(size));
    if (num==0 && flag==0) {
        flag=1;
        array[i]=0;
        i++;
    } else if(num==0 && flag==1) {
        continue;
    } else if(!checkVal(num, array)) {
        array[i]=num;
        i++;
    }
}
}
private static boolean checkVal(int val, int[] arr) {
    int i = 0;
    for (int num:arr) {
        if (num==val) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

2nd:

```
private void secondAlgorithm(int size) {
    int i = 0;
    int[] array = new int[size];
    boolean[] booleanArray = new boolean[size];

    while (i < array.length) {
        int num = (int) (Math.random() * array.length);
        if (!booleanArray[num]) {
            booleanArray[num] = true;
            array[i] = num;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

3rd:

```
private void thirdAlgorithm(int size) {
    int[] array = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int num = (int) (Math.random() * (i - 1));
        if (i > 0) {
            array = swap(array, i, num);
        }

    }
}
private static int[] swap(int[] arr, int a, int b) {
    int i = arr[a];
    arr[a] = arr[b];
    arr[b] = i;
    return arr;
}
```

Would be nice, if you could explain your results.
In my opinion, 1st - O(n^2) because of two loops, 2nd don't know, 3rd O(n)
THank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that in all your algorithms, where you are generating a random number, you meant to take the remainder of the generated number, not multiplying it with another value (example for the first algorithm: `Math.random() % size`). If this is not the case, then any of the above algorithms have a small chance of not finishing in a reasonable amount of time.

The first algorithm generates and fills an array of `size` integers. The rule is that the array must contain only one value of `0` and only distinct values. Checking if the array already contains a newly generated value is done in `O(m)` where `m` is the number of elements already inserted in the array. You might do this check for each of the `size` elements which are to be inserted and m can get as large as `size`, so an upper bound of the running-time is `O(size^2)`.

The second algorithm also generates and fills an array with random numbers, but this time the numbers need not be distinct, so no need to run an additional `O(m)` check each iteration. The overall complexity is given by the size of the array: `O(size)`.

The third algorithm generates and fills an array with random numbers and at each iteration it swaps some elements based on the given index, which is a constant time operation. Also, reassigning the reference of the array to itself is a constant time operation (`O(1)`). It results that the running-time is bounded by `O(size)`.

Comment: but this time the numbers need not be distinct, so no need to run an additional O(m) check each iteration - this check is performed in a different way, I am using a boolean array each iteration. but it still doesn't make difference, right?

Comment: That boolean array checks a different thing. It looks at the `num`th element in the array and it checks if it was previously assigned a value. That is, it verifies only one value, not `m` values, as in the first case. So no, it does not make any difference.